# batch script not working from .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I wrote this one liner that allow me to start pageant and load all `.ppk` files from my `%HOMEPATH%/.ssh` folder

Here is it:

```
start pageant && timeout 1 && FOR %k in ("%HOMEPATH%\.ssh\*.ppk") do start pageant %k
```

The timeout is there to prevent multiple pageant instances ( WIN7 only, I know )

So this works when just running it from the command line. Pageant starts and all keys load.

But now i want to put it in a `.bat` file so that i can add it in my `startup` folder.

I tried all these combinations:

```
start pageant && timeout 1 && FOR %k in ("%HOMEPATH%\.ssh\*.ppk") do start pageant %k

start pageant
timeout 1
FOR %k in ("%HOMEPATH%\.ssh\*.ppk") do start pageant %k

start pageant && timeout 1 && FOR %k in ("C:%HOMEPATH%\.ssh\*.ppk") do start pageant %k

start pageant
timeout 1
FOR %k in ("C:%HOMEPATH%\.ssh\*.ppk") do start pageant %k

start pageant && timeout 1 && FOR %k in ("C:\Users\Willem\.ssh\*.ppk") do start pageant %k

start pageant
timeout 1
FOR %k in ("C:\Users\Willem\.ssh\*.ppk") do start pageant %k
```

I also tried several options on FOR and tried removing and adding start everywhere.
And many more variations, i keep getting this error when the FOR loops runs

```
HOMEPATHk was unexpected at this time.
```

It's just not working when i try to run it through a .bat file. pageant.exe is added to my system32 folder, I'm using the latest stable version.

What rookie mistake am i missing here that this won't run from a batch file ?

Comment: In batch files for loop variables use the sintax `%%k`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double up your % to %% while running as a batch file.  It's a special character and must be escaped when run from batch, explaining why it works from the command line but not from batch file.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to call pageant with multiple parameters, instead of calling it multiple times:

```
pageant %a %b %c %d ...
```

It doesn't start any more if already opened.